# how to replace special character with empty string

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
str = '( name1 || name2 || name3 )'
```

and I want to replace '(' and ')' with the empty string

Have tried this but it didn't work

```
str.replace(/[()]+/g,'')
```

Please advice. I want the find string will be

```
str = 'name1 || name2 || name3'
```

Comment: It works for me, why you said it doesn't works?

Comment: Are you assigning the result to anything or using the result somehow? `str.replace(/[()]+/g,'')` alone doesn’t change `str`. `str = str.replace(/[()]+/g,'')` does.

Comment: var str2 = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);

Answer (score 3):

I mean, you've got most of it there:

```
var str = '( name1 || name2 || name3 )';
str = str.replace(/[()]+/g,'');
console.log(str);
```

I think you just forgot to assign `str` in the middle statement.  Also, you probably want to trim the middle:

```
str = str.replace(/[()]+/g,'').trim();
```

Comment: Just for some background for the OP: Strings are immutable, which means that none of the functions that can be executed on strings actually modify the original string. They will just return the resulting string. That's why assignment is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, How about I just want to replace the first '(' and the last ')' with empty string. So the var str = '( name1( || name2) || name3 )'; and the output should be  'name1( || name2) || name3'